# Is it possible to display standard salesforce lwc detail page of two different object side by side for comparison

Tags: detail-page

I am having a requirement to display saleforce contact object detail page and custom contact object  detail page to show side by side for comparison of data between two objects.
Is it possible to display the standard salesforce lwc detail page to show side by side in the same screen? If so, please advice how to proceed?
[image]

[image: Side by Side of detail view of two different object contact and Third party contact]

Comment: With app page and 2 custom page - its easily possible. With standard page of standard object and custom component of custom object still possible with the additional api property of relating the standard object or input box to give the record id of custom object

Comment: Can you please explain elobaratly. I am new to salesforce and not quite following your views.